# How can we take sum of unique data from array using php

Tags: php

I need to take sum of beds of unique date from array. I had tried with foreach but I am getting repeated data.

How can I get data like,

`on 01.08.18 I have 3 bookings and sum of beds is 10`

`on 02.08.18 I have 3 bookings and sum of beds is 18`

`on 03.08.18 I have 2 bookings and sum of beds is 7`

```
<?php
$dates = ['01.01.18', '02.01.18', '03.01.18']; //Dates are getting from daterange datepicker and preparing dates using php and stored in array. 
foreach($dates as $date) {
// fetching data from table where date is matching with "$date".
    $bookings = [
                 ['date' => '01.01.18', 'beds' => '2'],
                 ['date' => '01.01.18', 'beds' => '3'],
                 ['date' => '01.01.18', 'beds' => '5'],
                 ['date' => '02.01.18', 'beds' => '7'],
                 ['date' => '02.01.18', 'beds' => '6'],
                 ['date' => '02.01.18', 'beds' => '5'],
                 ['date' => '03.01.18', 'beds' => '2'],
                 ['date' => '03.01.18', 'beds' => '5'],
                ];

}
foreach($bookings as $booking) {
    print_r($booking['date']);
}
```

Comment: most easily done directly in your sql query (with SUM() and group by)! Please show how you get the data!

Comment: in php it would be a combination of array_filter() and [array_reduce()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-reduce.php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Checkout the live result here: https://3v4l.org/nHijY

```
$arr = array();

foreach($bookings as $booking) {
    $date = $booking['date'];

    if(array_key_exists($date, $arr))
        $arr[$date][] = $booking['beds'];
    else
        $arr[$date] = array($booking['beds']);
}

foreach($arr as $key => $value)
{
    $count = count($value);
    $sum = array_sum($value);

    echo "on {$key} I have {$count} bookings and sum of beds is {$sum}\r\n";
}
```

Comment: You could save yourself a bunch of `count()`s and `array_sum()`s by doing that work in your first foreach loop.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [array_reduce](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-reduce.php) to iterate over `bookings` array and for each booking update the sum if dates match:

**Using array_reduce**

[Online Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/9c80c80706ef2fc9305537ab64d8c82f70f0a5fb)

```
$result = array_reduce( $bookings, function ($carry, $booking) use ($dates) {

    $date = $booking['date'];

    // Go to the next iteration if date doesn't exist
    if ( !in_array( $date, $dates ) ) {
        return $carry;
    }

    // Update sum if we have the same date Otherwise create new array
    if ( isset( $carry[ $date ] ) ) {
        $carry[$date]['sum'] += $booking['beds'];
        $carry[$date]['count']++;
    } else {
        $carry[ $date ] = [ 'sum' => $booking['beds'], 'count' => 1 ];
    }

    return $carry;

});
```

**Using a simple foreach**

[Online Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/d1a931c3782aa239ee8b8f7e0d6b9838371e9d34)

```
$result = []; 

foreach($bookings as $booking) {

    $date = $booking['date'];

    // go to the next iteration if date doesn't exists
    if ( !in_array( $date, $dates ) ) {
        continue;
    }

    if ( isset( $result[ $date ] ) ) {
        $result[$date]['sum'] += $booking['beds'];
        $result[$date]['count']++;
    } else {
        $result[ $date ] = [ 'sum' => $booking['beds'], 'count' => 1 ];
    }

}
```

Comment: It seems to me that it would be better to reduce the `$bookings` array, to build an array with the counts and sums (e.g. see the first loop in [sinaza's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47462042/113938)).  The current approach of creating a `$dates` array and repeatedly filtering, plucking the beds, summing, is doing more work than is needed.

Comment: Yes, I do it now with only one loop